# Sharepoint 2013 Apps Authentication error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, 2013, sharepoint-addin

I develop a simple SharePoint Hosted App and deploy but when i open this app, there is popup for id and password. which id password i need to enter because they dont accept administrator id password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this happening on the local server? Is your app domain separate from your host domain? If so, you will need to [disable the loopback check](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861) to avoid this problem (since you wouldn't be able to add BackConnectionHostNames values to the registry for every dynamically generated app URL).